# TextView height according to the screen size

Tags: java, android, textview

I need to place `TextView` at the Top of the screen.
In different situations its height is different.
I want to make `TextView` scrollable if it spaces more than 40% of the screen.
Of course if it has 3 words only it must space only a row.

Any idea?

Comment: I didn't understand what you are trying to achieve, can you explain a bit more in depth or provide some examples? (Maybe a crude drawing in paint).

Comment: https://github.com/intuit/sdp

Comment: Use maxHeight tag for text height extend to maximum  height upto..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**SDP - a scalable size unit**](https://github.com/intuit/sdp)

An android SDK that provides a new size unit - sdp (scalable dp). This size unit scales with the screen size. It can help Android developers with supporting multiple screens.

For **Texts** Use [**SSP - a scalable size unit for texts**](https://github.com/intuit/ssp)

An android SDK that provides a new size unit - ssp (scalable sp). This size unit scales with the screen size based on the sp size unit (for texts). It can help Android developers with supporting multiple screens.

Try any of these. I think these will help you alot

Answer (score 0):

Give    `android:layout_weight="1"` in xml
and use `textSize in sp not dp`

Answer (score 0):

Use dimen file for setting text size  &  give padding